# Error running test with Cucumber-jvm using Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, bdd

I am trying to run an sample of BDD test using Cucumber-jvm, but it give me an error:

The error is it:

My feature is the following:

```
Feature: enter a text and verify the output

Scenario: Verify that the text entered is displayed correctly
        Given I am launching the application
        When I submit a text
        Then I receive the same text on the next page
```

This is where i implement the last sentences, in the file MainActivitySpecs.java:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.testapp.MainActivity;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;

public class MainActivitySteps extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>{

    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    private String textToEnter = "test text";

    public MainActivitySteps() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Given("^I am launching the application$")
    public void I_am_launching_the_application() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mainActivity = getActivity();

        textView = (TextView) mainActivity.findViewById(com.example.testapp.R.id.edit_message);
        button = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(com.example.testapp.R.id.button);

        assertTrue("mainACtivity is null",mainActivity != null);
    }

    @When("^I submit a text$")
    public void I_submit_a_text() throws Exception {
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.requestFocus();
                textView.setText(textToEnter);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Then("^I receive the same text on the next page$")
    public void I_receive_the_same_text_on_the_next_page() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        button.callOnClick();

        assertEquals("The displayed text is not correct", textToEnter,textView.getText().toString());
    }
```

And my Runner is:

```
@RunWith (Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"}, 
features ="assets/features")
public class RunTest {
 }
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:allowBackup="true">
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>


<instrumentation
        android:name="cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentation"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.testapp" />
```

And the error is:

[image: this is the error]

Am i missing something?
I am using Intellij IDE.